# The configure() method not getting called in Apache camel routing

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, camel-routes

I am trying to use camel routing in my SpringBoot project. I have created a class named CamelFileRoute that extends `RouteBuilder`. When I log something inside the constructor, it is printed in the console. However, the logs inside the `configure()` method are not getting printed. Why is the configure method not getting called?

Below is my code-

```java
package com.reet.camel.route;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.extern.java.Log;

@Component
public class CamelFileRoute extends RouteBuilder{
    
    public CamelFileRoute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        System.out.println("Inside constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        System.out.println("Inside configure");
        
        from("file:files/input")
        .log("${body}")
        .to("file:files/output")
        .log("${body}");
        
    }

}
```

Expected output-
`Inside constructor`
`Inside configure`

Actual output-
`Inside constructor`

Comment: what dependencies have you added in pom.xml?

Comment: @VigneshNayakManel
I am using gradle project and below is my dependency 
`implementation group: 'org.apache.camel.springboot', name: 'camel-spring-boot-starter', version: '3.7.2'`

Comment: How do you start your app ? Do yo have a main class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and specifying the packages to scan ? See ex at https://www.baeldung.com/apache-camel-spring-boot